# Undefined mysql_connect in terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm using LAMPP with Ubuntu 64 bit.
When I try to execute php file using terminal,undefined mysql_connect error is given.But everything works fine when I'm using browser to load my php file.
I tried to edit the php.ini with remove the semicolon in front of extension=mysql.so then restart lampp,but with a error "unable to load dynamic library".
What can I do to solve this problem? This is important for me because I need to run my php script using crontab.

Thank you.

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/setrandomport-message.php on line 15`

`extension=msql.so`

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: @nickgrim Thanks for your reply,I edit the question.

Comment: That error message is for `msql` not `mysql` - they're different.

Comment: @nickgrim So what should I do now?I just having the "undefined mysql_connect" in terminal but not browser..

Comment: How did you install the php cli?

Comment: @Zoredache I not really remember the command line,something like sudo apt-get install php5-cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like you are confused because you have two separate versions of php.

You have the version that came as part of your lampp package in `/opt/lampp/` and you have the php-cli that you installed via the package manager.  The short answer is simply install the php5-mysql module via the package manager as well `apt-get install php5-mysql`.

You cannot mix and match modules between different versions of PHP.  If you choose to have two separate installations, you must maintain them separately.

Comment: Thank you so much Zoredache. so now I have 2 seperate PHP...sorry I'm new in Ubuntu and PHP so I don't know much about it...how I going to use one only(LAMP) for running in terminal and browser?

Comment: @IreneLing My suggestion would be to keep the one you're using and uninstall the other.  If you are unfamiliar with how to install/remove software on your chosen operating system refer to the vendor's instructions/support forums...